# DDL change in multiple postgresql instances at the same time?

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, ddl, database-administration

There are 4 postgresql instances running on 1 server. I want to make ddl change in all of them at same time.

How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks for removing the re-post.

Answer (score 3):

Write a shell script (if you're on *nix) or `.cmd` batch file / `.vbs` (if you're on Windows) to do it. Have the script invoke `psql -f /path/to/ddl.sql` and the IP/port, database name, etc.

Alternately, write a script in a language like Python that has proper PostgreSQL bindings. Have the script loop through the databases and run the DDL for each. In Python, for example, the following (untested) script should do the trick:

```python
import psycopg2
conn_definitions = [
    "dbname=db1 port=5432 host=127.0.0.1",
    "dbname=db2 port=5432 host=127.0.0.1",
    "dbname=db3 port=5432 host=127.0.0.1",
    "dbname=db4 port=5432 host=127.0.0.1",
]
ddl = """
    CREATE TABLE blah (
        blah integer
    );
    CREATE INDEX blah_blah_idx ON blah(blah);
"""
connections = []
cursors = []
for conn_info in conn_definitions:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_info)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    cursors.append(curs)
    connections.append(conn)
 for curs in cursors:
    curs.execute("BEGIN;")
 for curs in cursors:
    curs.execute(ddl)
 for curs in cursors:
    curs.execute("COMMIT;")
 for conn in connections:
    conn.close()
```

Enhance if desired by doing things like splitting the DDL into an array of statements you loop over so you can do per-statement error handling.

You could also generate the connections dynamically by connecting to one DB for each host and running `select datname from pg_database` to get a listing of other DBs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not an answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: @TraviJuu Then you need to clarify your question to explain what you *do* want, in detail, because this explains how to do what you asked. You can edit your question to add more information.

Comment: by using triggers and dblink?

Comment: @TraviJuu PostgreSQL has no DDL triggers, so you can't have a DDL change in one database trigger DDL changes in other databases via dblink. Again, you need to explain in more detail what you want to do and why. Edit your question and elaborate.